# Enum conversion to Enumeration class with small Business Logic inside

Tags: c#, .net, enum

I had old `enum`, I converted it to Enumeration class and added one method inside (`isValid`). I am not sure if it is good approach to add such small business logic into Enumeration class. I would like to understand if this is a good approach or not.

Here is **old** `enum`:

```
internal enum Rule
{
    None = 0,

    CompensationIsZero = 1,

    CompensationLessThanDemand = 2,

    CompensationBetweenZeroAndDemand = 3,

    CompensationEqualsDemand = 4,

    CompensationLessOrEqualsDemand = 5
}
```

Here it is rewritten to `Enumeration` class and `IsValid` method is added.

```
 public class Rule : Enumeration
{
        public static readonly Rule None = new Rule (0, "None");
        public static readonly Rule CompensationIsZero  = new Rule (1, "CompensationIsZero ");
        public static readonly Rule CompensationLessThanDemand = new Rule(2, "CompensationLessThanDemand "); 
       .... 
       // there are about 5 rules

       public Rule(int id, string name)
        : base(id, name)
       { }

        public bool IsValid(decimal compensation, decimal demand, int rule) {
                if (rule == Rule.None.Id) return true;
                if (rule == Rule.CompensationIsZero.Id) then return compensation == 0;
                if (rule == Rule.CompensationLessThanDemand .Id) then return compensation < demand;

                ...
         }
}
```

`Enumeration` class implementation version is very similar like in this article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types)

Thus I have values `compensation` and `demand` (these come from UI). 
And I have some type based on which I get Rule value from database.
And so I call method `IsValid (compensation, demand, ruleIdFromDb)`. If it is not validated then I show error on UI.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the 'IsValid' method be static? I suppose you use it like `Rule.IsValid(calculatedCompensation, 0, Rule.CompensationIsZero.Id)`, (as general idea, obviously it can be simplified).

Anyway PERSONALLY I would not do this, because `Rule` is no more an `Enum`, you gave it logic, that usually `Enum` don't have. I would have keep the `Enum` as original and built on top of that a `Class` with the required logic. (Maybe called `RuleValidator` with a static method `public static bool IsValid(Rule rule, decimal compensation, decimal demand) {...}`.

If this does not concern you, than another way could be to write an extension method:

```cs
static class RuleExtensions 
{
  public static bool Validate(this Rule rule, decimal compensation, decimal demand) 
  {
    switch (rule) 
    {
      case None: return true;
      case CompensationIsZero: return compensation == 0;
      case CompensationLessThanDemand : return compensation < demand;
      // ecc...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your comment make sense.

Comment: can I ask one more question, what if I would like to have different error messages based on which Case failed. Should I add static property ErrorMessage or should error message be returned from Validate?

Comment: I can't think a super elegant solution, I'm still junior. But I would go for something like `public static bool Validate (this Rule rule, decimal compensation, decimal demand, out string errorMessage) {...}`. Usage: `if (!Rule.None.Validate.(10, 0, out var error)) Console.WriteLine(error);`. Inside `Validate` then, before returning false, you would set `errorMessage` with a string retrieved form some kind of external resource (like the .resx files, or a DB). This because you could need the message to change (like for localization).